# What are the risk factors currently thought important for disease severity in COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19

I have heard of from reading numerous journal articles, and newspaper/TV reports:

- age > 70
- age < 5
- obesity
- smoker cigarettes or pot
- male
- blood group not group O
- poor socio economic status
- crowded and multi-generational living
- [black](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23202), hispanic
- hypertension
- cardio respiratory disease
- diabetes 1+2
- immunosuppression
- cancer
- religious beliefs

Note that some of these are inextricably linked to each other.

Any others?

Comment: I dont think there is any evidence of race being a risk factor, I would like to see your sources.

Comment: *Religious beliefs?* I don't think whatever source you got this list from is trustworthy.

Comment: If you require explanation then one process is to ask another question.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Your question would be improved by providing references for race and religion. I know why you included those, but not everyone might.

Comment: I think it would make a great, or, perhaps controversial question.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica If your religious belief requires you to sit together with a few hundred people for a few hours a week, then of course it's a risk factor.

Comment: @user253751 Indeed, this is the poster child for "religious beliefs" being a factor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shincheonji_Church_of_Jesus#Association_with_the_coronavirus_outbreak

Comment: @GrahamChiu I've got no problem at all with great or controversial questions.

Comment: @CareyGregory well, I've asked the question

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.businessinsider.com/us-coronavirus-hospitalizations-underlying-health-conditions-cdc-2020-3 ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200412111344/https://www.businessinsider.com/us-coronavirus-hospitalizations-underlying-health-conditions-cdc-2020-3), [mirror 2](http://archive.is/WJsGC)):

[image]

Transcription...

> Counts are among the 7162 cases with completed information on pre-existing conditions:
>
> - Chronic liver disease
> - Current smoker
> - Former smoker
> - Chronic renal disease
> - Immunocompromised
> - Cardiovascular disease
> - Chronic lung disease
> - Diabetes mellitus
> - Other chronic disease

Source: CDC Data as of March 28, 2020 at 12 pm EST.

Also: [What are the genetic predispositions, if any, for covid-19?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/23128/43)

Comment: Hasn't really added to what I know. Anything else?

Comment: @GrahamChiu e.g. chronic lung/liver disease. Also added some severity metrics.

Answer (score 3):

A pre-publication study at NYU in New York City looked at the risk factors for more severe COVID-19 disease.

These risks included older age, especially age over 75, as well as obesity (BMI>40), and congestive heart failure, which conferred dramatically higher odds of being hospitalized for COVID-19.

The strongest risk factor was low oxygen levels upon presentation in the E.R.

https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.04.08.20057794v1

According to the authors’ abstract:

> Strongest hospitalization risks were age ≥75 years (OR 66.8, 95% CI,
>   44.7-102.6), age 65-74 (OR 10.9, 95% CI, 8.35-14.34), BMI>40 (OR 6.2, 95% CI, 4.2-9.3), and heart failure (OR 4.3 95% CI, 1.9-11.2).
>   Strongest critical illness risks were admission oxygen saturation <88%
>   (OR 6.99, 95% CI 4.5-11.0), d-dimer>2500 (OR 6.9, 95% CI, 3.2-15.2),
>   ferritin >2500 (OR 6.9, 95% CI, 3.2-15.2), and C-reactive protein
>   (CRP) >200 (OR 5.78, 95% CI, 2.6-13.8). In the decision tree for
>   admission, the most important features were age >65 and obesity; for
>   critical illness, the most important was SpO2<88, followed by
>   procalcitonin >0.5, troponin <0.1 (protective), age >64 and CRP>200.
>   Conclusions: Age and comorbidities are powerful predictors of
>   hospitalization; however, admission oxygen impairment and markers of
>   inflammation are most strongly associated with critical illness.

Comment: High CRP and ferritin are markers for IL-6 suggestive of ARDS